# Why is Torus a Kahler manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, kahler-manifolds, holonomy

I've run into the following issue. I want to understand why a torus $T = \mathbb C^n / \Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a lattice, is a Kähler manifold?

Now, Wikipedia seems to suggest that it is because it inherits a flat metric coming from $\mathbb C^n$.

For me, to show Torus is a Kähler manifold would require to find a real $(1,1)$ form which is closed and a bunch of compatibility conditions.

> 1. How does **flat** metric imply any of this?

Elsewhere on Wikipedia itself they say a manifold is Kahler iff it is a $2n$ dim Riemannian manifold whose holonomy group is contained inside $U(n)$.

> 2. Does a flat connection have holonomy group inside $U(n)$? Why?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The Kähler form is given by $\omega(X,Y) = g(JX,Y)$ where $g$ is the Riemannian metric and $J$ the complex structure on $T$ induced by the usual euclidean metric and complex structure of $\Bbb C^n$, which are invariant under the action of $\Lambda$.

Comment: Flat connections have trivial *restricted* holonomy (correction on my now-deleted answer), so in particular contained in $U(n)$, but this does not directly tell us about the unrestricted holonomy.